# Is it possible to generate expressJS app from serverless.yml?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have got aws lambda app, discribed by serverless.yml comfig file. I need to start my application localy. Is there any aws mock for node to run aws lamdas localy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda can be used to run Lambdas locally (go to https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/ and pull a container with nodejs tag).

How well it will work for you depends on what exactly your Lambda does - if it is not too tightly coupled to AWS it will probably be okay but if it makes use of other AWS services then it may not work so well as the above project only emulates the Lambda runtime, not all of AWS.

Comment: You are right. Even after installing offline mock (https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline/) for aws lambda, i still have problems with aws cognito

Comment: It may be worth looking at https://github.com/localstack/localstack (I haven't used it myself though so I'm not sure how much setup/config is required).